# Loop function for 3 variables

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, integer

i need to create loop for 3 variables ( gas station, hotel , food joint ) for same set of function to be executed one after other one after other ,.. it would be great if any one can guide me on it

i had tried same in C , can any one please help me to do it Python

```
CHAR sMenuNames[3][30]={ {'GAS STATTION'}, {'Hotel'}, {'Restaurant'} }
CHAR sCurrentMenuName[30];
INTEGER nCount;
INTEGER nMaxCount =4;
For(ncount=1;nCount<=nMaxCount;ncount++)
{
sCurrentMenuName=sMenuNames[ncount]
//EXECUTE_FUNCTIONS(sCurrentMenuName);
wait 20 
}
```

Need it for automation profile ( python robotframe script  )

Comment: Please provide the expected input and output, that would help to make the question better :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be of help. I tried to write your code in python.

```
import time

variables = ['GAS STATTION', 'Hotel', 'Restaurant']

for item in variables:
    #run your functions here
    func1(item)
    func2(item)
    func3(item)

    #similar to your wait(20)
    time.sleep(20)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want something like this.

```
menu_names = ['GAS STATION', 'Hotel', 'Restaurant']
for menu_name in menu_names:
   execute_functions(menu_name)
```

There is no need to define the size of strings and lists. You don't need an index to access each element in a list for you can just iterate over it.